# How to process Bootstrap with less.rb outside of Rails

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm attempting to create a standalone application (independent of the Rails asset pipeline) using less.rb to output CSS files based upon Twitter Bootstrap.

The following results in an empty document

```
parser = Less::Parser.new :paths => [Rails.root + '/public/bootstraps/twitter-bootstrap-857b8fb/less']

tree = parser.parse("@import 'bootstrap.less'")

tree.to_css
```

Which results in an empty string being returned. I've tried variations of altering the @import to be the full path etc, with no success. I think I must be missing something simple.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have an issue with how you are specifying your path.  As far as I can tell, *Less* is looking for an array of `String` objects, not `Path` obejcts.

Use the following:

```
parser = Less::Parser.new paths: [Rails.root.join('public', 'bootstraps', 'twitter-bootstrap-857b8fb', 'less').to_s]

tree = parser.parse("@import 'bootstrap.less'")

tree.to_css
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple run `make` as you have described here: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/wiki/Contributing-to-Bootstrap

Comment: I believe that that actually executes from the node side of things (which I'd like to avoid if possible).

Comment: It's rather imposible to compile Less without additional software. If you never ever wanna run any other app you can compile Less on the client side,  but IMHO it's not a good idea.

Comment: Less.rb is the 'additional software' in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is not of utmost concern, you can always include less.js, which will compile the less files at runtime. Detailed instructions [here](http://lesscss.org/#-client-side-usage).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the filename syntax from the less.rb github page? https://github.com/cowboyd/less.rb/

```
parser = Less::Parser.new :paths => ['./lib', 'other/lib'], :filename => 'mystyles.less'
```